# Spring Data REST - projection of association of the abstract type

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Having following entities (irrelevant fields ommitted):

```
@Entity
public class TransferConfiguration {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "RECIPIENT_ID", nullable = false)
    private Party recipient;    
}  

@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public abstract class Party {

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("C")
public class Customer extends Party {

} 

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("O")
public class OtherParty extends Party {

}
```

The association is based on abstract class.

Now I would like to have link to the association when I get my resource, but Spring Data REST always inlines the association, giving no link in the _links section of resulting JSON.

The output looks following:

```
{
  "recipient": {
    // recipient attributes inlined here
  },
  // other attributes here
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://myhost/api/transferConfigurations/20"
    },
    "transferConfiguration": {
      "href": "http://myhost/api/transferConfigurations/20"
    }
  }
}
```

I have repository interfaces for both concrete classes (Customer, OtherParty), but not for the superclass itself. Now when spring-data-rest decides whether to inline the association or not, it tries to find the interface for the Party superclass, which does not exists and therefore the association is inlined.

Is it possible to alter the behaviour somehow?

I would like to have a link instead of inlined association. Like this:

```
{
  // other attributes here
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://myhost/api/transferConfigurations/20"
    },
    "transferConfiguration": {
      "href": "http://myhost/api/transferConfigurations/20"
    },
    "recipient": {
      "href": "http://myhost/api/transferConfigurations/20/recipient"
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally did some research on the topic and and the scenario above is simply not possible to implement in Spring Data Rest (I was using version 2.4.1.RELEASE).

The problem lies in a way how the association type is determined. SDR uses JPA metamodel (rather than examinig actual payload being serialized)  to dermine the type, which is obviously the supertype (`Party` in this case). 
Then framework checks if there's a repository for that type, and since there's not, the association is inlined.

The problematic code is in the class `AssociationLinks`, method `isLinkableAssociation()`, where `metadata.isExported()` checks whether the repository is exported based on the association supertype.

```
public boolean isLinkableAssociation(PersistentProperty<?> property) {

    if (property == null || !property.isAssociation()) {
        return false;
    }

    ResourceMetadata metadata = mappings.getMetadataFor(property.getOwner().getType());

    if (metadata != null && !metadata.isExported(property)) {
        return false;
    }

    metadata = mappings.getMetadataFor(property.getActualType());
    return metadata == null ? false : metadata.isExported();
}
```

In the end, I did bite the bullet and exported the superclass repository in order the have the links.

Answer (score 0):

Spring data rest is embedding an association if the target entity has no repository defined or the repository is not exported. I would try to create a repository for Customer/OtherParty/Party.

Also it would be interesting to know how your Party superclass is mapped - is it a  `@MappedSuperclass`

Comment: I have improved the description. The `Party` is not `@MappedSuperclass` (I'm using SINGLE_TABLE inheritance strategy), and there's no repository for it. I have a repositories only for concrete classes (`Customer`,`OtherParty`).